# Python: understanding iterators and `join()` better

Tags: python, python-internals

The `join()` function accepts an iterable as parameter. However, I was wondering why having:

```
text = 'asdfqwer'
```

This:

```
''.join([c for c in text])
```

Is significantly faster than:

```
''.join(c for c in text)
```

The same occurs with long strings (i.e. `text * 10000000`).

Watching the memory footprint of both executions with long strings, I think they both create one and only one list of chars in memory, and then join them into a string. So I am guessing perhaps the difference is only between how `join()` creates this list out of the generator and how the Python interpreter does the same thing when it sees `[c for c in text]`. But, again, I am just guessing, so I would like somebody to confirm/deny my guesses.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Where do you see a tuple here?

Comment: @Matthias ya, wrongly mentioned as tuple instead of generator.

Comment: Presumably you're referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/3001761

Comment: Interestingly list is also faster on my system than iterating over the string directly: `''.join(text)`

Comment: To see for yourself: `python -m timeit 'text = "asdfqwer" * 10000000; "".join([c for c in text])'` (and also without `[]`). I get `2.04 sec per loop` with the list, `2.9 sec per loop` with the generator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `join` method reads its input twice; once to determine how much memory to allocate for the resulting string object, then again to perform the actual join. Passing a list is faster than passing a generator object that it needs to make a copy of so that it can iterate over it twice.

A list comprehension is not simply a generator object wrapped in a list, so constructing the list externally is faster than having `join` create it from a generator object. Generator objects are optimized for memory efficiency, not speed.

Of course, a string is *already* an iterable object, so you could just write `''.join(text)`. (Also again this is not as fast as creating the list explicitly from the string.)

Comment: I just tested this with a generator that prints. `join` did not execute the generator twice. It's a fairly far-fetched claim. What makes you think it executes the generator twice?

Comment: @DanielDarabos *"that it needs to make a copy of"* - by consuming it into a list!

Comment: Reproducing my question comment here since you mentioned it in your answer: Interestingly `timeit` on my system shows that a list is faster than the direct string iteration here as well.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that's because [`PySequence_Fast`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/abstract.c#l1768) only special-cases lists and tuples - everything else (including strings) gets processed one extra time.

Comment: Generator objects are slow. They are optimized for memory usage, not speed of iteration. Creating a list from an existing generator takes more time than building the list using a list comprehension. (Despite the similarity in syntax, a list comprehension is not just a generator object wrapped in a list.)

Comment: @chepner I am wondering why generator produced by generator expression is slower? Why is not it optimized in form of some PyGenerator_Fast

Comment: @Andrey That's not a very good test because you're using a short-cicruiting function and we're talking about one that has to reprocess a generator (and therefore must make a copy). Additionally, in your test, generators were _still_ very slightly slower (though not significantly).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist in this example it doesn't short circuit. all will not stop while true (1).

Comment: @Andrey Yes, but that's not the point. `all` must use the generator at most once. `join` must use the generator _at least twice_.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist my comment was not really about join, it was response to comment "Generator objects are slow."

Comment: @Peque That's the only way it's possible to use a generator twice.