# How is str.join(iterable) method implemented in Python/ Linear time string concatenation

Tags: python, string, algorithm, string-concatenation

I am trying to implement my own `str.join` method in Python, e.g:
`''.join(['aa','bbb','cccc'])` returns `'aabbbcccc'`. I know that string concatenation using the join method would result in linear (in the number of characters of the result) complexity, and I want to know how to do it, as using the `'+'` operator in a for loop would result in quadratic complexity e.g.:

```
res=''
for word in ['aa','bbb','cccc']:
  res = res +  word
```

As strings are immutable, this copies a new string at each iteration resulting in quadratic running time. However, I want to know how to do it in linear time or find how `''.join` works exactly.

I could not find anywhere a linear time algorithm nor the implementation of str.join(iterable). Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you want to check the built-in str.join code. Potentially here's how - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions

Comment: You can try ```+=```

Comment: I imagine the c code implementation pre-calculates the result length and does a single buffer assignment for the result. Why not look at the source code rather than speculate?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782238/550094 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462194/python-understanding-iterators-and-join-better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joining `str` as actual `str` is a red herring and [not what Python itself does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/stringlib/join.h): Python operates on mutable `bytes`, not the `str`, which also removes the need to [know string internals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/). In specific, `str.join` converts its arguments to bytes, then [pre-allocates](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/83ca46b7784b7357d82ec47b33295e09ed7380cb/Objects/stringlib/join.h#L57-L111) and [*mutates* its result](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/83ca46b7784b7357d82ec47b33295e09ed7380cb/Objects/stringlib/join.h#L123-L144).

This directly corresponds to:

1. a wrapper to encode/decode `str` arguments to/from `bytes`
2. summing the `len` of elements and separators
3. allocating a mutable `bytesarray` to construct the result
4. copying each element/separator directly into the result

```py
# helper to convert to/from joinable bytes
def str_join(sep: "str", elements: "list[str]") -> "str":
    joined_bytes = bytes_join(
        sep.encode(),
        [elem.encode() for elem in elements],
    )
    return joined_bytes.decode()

# actual joining at bytes level
def bytes_join(sep: "bytes", elements: "list[bytes]") -> "bytes":
    # create a mutable buffer that is long enough to hold the result
    total_length = sum(len(elem) for elem in elements)
    total_length += (len(elements) - 1) * len(sep)
    result = bytearray(total_length)
    # copy all characters from the inputs to the result
    insert_idx = 0
    for elem in elements:
        result[insert_idx:insert_idx+len(elem)] = elem
        insert_idx += len(elem)
        if insert_idx < total_length:
            result[insert_idx:insert_idx+len(sep)] = sep
            insert_idx += len(sep)
    return bytes(result)

print(str_join(" ", ["Hello", "World!"]))
```

Notably, while the element iteration and element copying basically are two nested loops, they iterate over separate things. The algorithm still touches each character/byte only thrice/once.

Comment: Thank you for your time and for your answer! I think I understand it now. However, do you know why when I ran your str_join function and the string concatenation with loop, the one with the loop is  much faster? On my computer I tried to time it with Python's time module and the loop version takes 0.49sec, whereas str_join takes 2.37 sec.

Comment: The ``+``/``+=`` operation for ``str`` is implemented in pure C and thus very performant. Even though *in theory* its complexity is worse, *in practice* it has a much better constant factor.